# Convertir imágen a application/octet-stream en Javascript (subir imágen a arweave)

Tags: javascript, blockchain

Quiero subir imágenes a Arweave, utilizando JavaScript tengo este código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la hora de recibir el archivo lo recibo a través de input type="file" pero para subir a Arweave debo pasar como data algo que no sé que es. Estoy utilizando el paquete de npm Arweave.

Alguien porfa puede ayudarme diciendome como le hago para subir la imágen a Arweave, o como puedo convertir un objeto File a application/octet-stream Para poder ponerlo como data.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que es codigo debes colocarlo no como una imagen, si no como codigo, el editor tiene la opcion para formatearlo como codigo, esto se hace por cuestiones de facilidad a la hora de probar algun codigo aqui en stack overflow, ya de una vez aprovecho y te doy la bienvenida, te invito a darte un paseo por el [tour] y a leer [ask], para que puedas entender de mejor forma como funciona el sitio, no te preocupes no es un regaño ni nada, simplemente es una introduccion que se le da a los nuevos usuarios en stackoverflow como orientacion.

Comment: Lo otro es, el mime type `application/octet-stream` es un formato binario por defecto el cual es el que tiene cualquier archivo, lo que pasa es que este es un formato generico que colocan los sistemas operativos cuando el sistema falla en reconocer un mime type adecuado para abrir el formato, por ejemplo, si tuviesemos una imagen y la imagen no tiene en su nombre su extension entonces javascript es un poco tonto al respecto y no te va a detectar que es una imagen, y simplemente te coloca el formato en `octet-stream` como default.

Comment: Esto muchas veces hace que si por ejemplo intentas cargar un pdf en formato `base64` en un sitio, al tener el mime type seteado como `application/octet-stream` no te va a poder cargar bien el pdf o no te lo mostrara como tu quieres, la solucion muchas veces es simplemente reemplazar ese mime type con el aduecuado si sabes con seguridad el formato original del archivo.

Comment: Igual se que esto no soluciona tu problema ni lo que necesitas, pero es informacion util que me gustaria que tuvieses en cuenta mas adelante.

Comment: Lo otro es... nunca he usado arwave, por lo que no sabria bien como resolver tu problema, pero te doy una pista, deberias buscar en la documentacion de arweave un metodo que te permita pasar como argumento un tipo file directamente, estoy seguro de que debe haberlo, no tienes que convertir nada, porque recuerda que el `octet-stream` es el formato por defecto, ademas debes tener cuidado al colocar `addTag` con el argumento `image/png`, ya que recuerda que las imagenes pueden tener muchos formatos diferentes y no solo png, alli estas limitando a solo un formato y fallara en cualquier otro.

Answer (score 0):

Al subir un archivo a un input de tipo `file`, el input permite referenciar lo subido en una propiedad `files` que es un array de `File` (subclase de Blob). En un input no múltiple este array siempre tiene un solo elemento así que

```
 const archivo = input.files[0]
```

Supongo que ya llegaste a esa parte porque en tu código aparece `file`.

Por otro lado, si miramos [el código de Arweave](https://github.com/ArweaveTeam/arweave-js/blob/3e0841351744d159ab5f3c84462ca780b5462876/src/common/common.ts#L19-L30), la interfaz de `createTransaction` dice:

```
export interface CreateTransactionInterface {
  // otras propiedades...
  data: string | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer;
  // más propiedades...
}
```

Como `File` hereda de `Blob`, puedes leerlo como arrayBuffer. Obtendrás una promesa que se resuelve como ídem:

```js
const input=document.getElementById("archivo")
input .addEventListener("change", async (event) => {
  const archivo = event.target.files[0];

  const arrayBuffer = await archivo.arrayBuffer()
  // arweave.createTransaction({data: arrayBuffer},key)
  console.log('Es un arraybuffer?',arrayBuffer instanceof ArrayBuffer);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="archivo"/>
```

Y el arrayBuffer es lo que le pasas a `data` para postearlo al servicio que mencionas.

De todos modos, no sé si me da buena espina tener tu llave en el browser. Sólo lo digo como observación gratuita.